# How to know when the VerticalScrollBar is showing?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I need to know when the `verticalScrollBar` of my `QTableWidget` is being shown.
I am currently using the following instruction:

Header:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QScrollBar>

namespace Ui {
class MyClass;
}

class MyClass: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyClass();

private:
    void populateTable(QVector<QString> content);

private:
    Ui::MyClass *ui;
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

Populate table function:

```
void MyClass::populateTable(QVector<QString> content)
{
    while( ui->myTableWidget->rowCount() > 0 )
    {
        ui->myTableWidget->removeRow(0);
    }

    QTableWidgetItem* item;
    for (int row = 0; row < content.length(); ++row)
    {
        ui->myTableWidget->insertRow(row);

        item = new QTableWidgetItem( QString::number(row) );
        item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        ui->myTableWidget->setItem(row, 0, item);

        item = new QTableWidgetItem( content.at(row) );
        item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        ui->myTableWidget->setItem(row, 1, item);
    }

    qDebug() << "This : " << this->isVisible();
    qDebug() << "QTableWidget : " << ui->myTableWidget->isVisible();
    qDebug() << "VerticalScrollBar : " << ui->myTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->isVisible(); // <-HERE
}
```

Output:

```
// Called from the constructor
This :  false
QTableWidget :  false
VerticalScrollBar :  false

// Called by a button pressed
This :  true
QTableWidget :  true
VerticalScrollBar :  true
This :  true
QTableWidget :  true
VerticalScrollBar :  false
```

But it returns a wrong value. When the **ScrollBar** is visible it returns false and when it is not visible it returns true. **Note**: myTableWidget (`QTableWidget`) is always visible.

Is there any other way that I can do this?

I'm using Qt version 5.3.2

Answer (score 4):

In general the code you are using is supposed to work - checked on Qt 5.3.0.

However, you must be sure that when you are making the call the `QTableWidget` itself is visible.

For example if you make the call inside the `MainWindow` constructor you will certainly get a `false` answer. Only after the form is shown the call to isVisible() on particular scrollbar would return the correct value.

**EDIT:**

With your code pasted I was able to reproduce the issue. I needed to go through the Qt code a bit to see whats going on. Basically it turns out that for `QTableView` which is parent class of `QTableWidget` scroll bar values are updated via `updateGeometries` (do not confuse it with the regular `updateGeometry` the one I'm mentioning is `protected`). Internally this method is called either directly or the event is processed through the event loop. In short, it depends on whether you add columns or rows.

In your example, if you `insertColumn` instead of `insertRow` (and switch the arguments in `setItem`) after checking the visibility of `horizontalScrollBar` you will get the proper result right away.

I could confirm this by subclassing the `QTableWidget` and overriding `event` method. It shows that when adding columns following events are executed: `MetaCall` (invoke call) and `LayoutRequest`. On the other hand, when adding rows first event passed is `Timer`.

I'm not Qt implementer so I'm not sure what is the purpose the difference. However, this info helps solving your problem in a more elegant way.

You can implement `MyTableWidget` which overrides the `event` method.

```
class MyTableWidget: public QTableWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    bool event(QEvent *e) override
    {
        const bool result = QTableWidget::event(e);
        if (e->type() == QEvent::LayoutRequest)
        {
            // call what you need here
            // or emit layoutUpdated(); and connect some slots which perform
            // processing dependent on scrollbar visibility
        }
        return result;
    }

signals:
    void layoutUpdated();
}
```

However, such event might get called in other situations not only when the view needs to be updated due to model data updates.

Another solution would be to avoid overriding the `event` method but creating your own method to trigger the required updates. For example:

```
void MyTableWidget::updateLayout()
{
    QEvent ev{QEvent::LayoutRequest};
    QTableWidget::updateGeometries();
    QTableWidget::event(&ev);
}
```

This would call directly `updateGeometries` which recalculates scrollbar min/max values and perform a direct `event` method call for `LayoutRequest` (without processing through eventloop). Which if I'm correct indirectly updates scrollbar visibility.

Calling this method before checking the visibility should also fix your problem.

```
ui->myTableWidget->updateLayout();
qDebug() << "VerticalScrollBar : " << ui->myTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->isVisible();
// prints "VerticalScrollBar :  true   false"
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to get notified via a signal, when a QScrollBar gets visible. I'm writing this answer here, since this is the first google result I got and no result had a proper answer.

First of all, there is no signal for changed visibility, so we will use [`valueChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged).

Now you can add a function that checks if the scrollbar `isVisible()` or not.
Problem: It won't work (and someone with more knowledge in Qt could probably explain why, I sadly cannot).

The trick is, to use a QTimer (Python code):

`self.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(lambda x: QTimer.singleShot(0,  some_func))`

Comment: That put me on the right track. Although I had to use the rangeChanged signal to catch the scrollbar apearance.