# how to specify the height of scrollbar in QTreeView

Tags: qt, scrollbar, qtreeview, redraw

just like the title described, when i redraw the scrollbar in QTreeView which has a header(QHeaderView), but the scrollbar's height is the entire height of QTreeView, and i want to let the scrollbar's height equals the QTreeView's height minus the header's height.just like the pic below:
[image: just like this, exclude the height of header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for your problem might be setting the location of the vertical scrollbar to a `constant_offset` value acquired from the `QHeaderView` (on the y axis).

This could be done by subclassing the `QTreeView` like so:

```
class MyTreeView : public QTreeView
{
public:
    MyTreeView(QWidget* parent = nullptr): QTreeView(parent){}

    void updateVertScrollBar()
    {
        auto* ptr = verticalScrollBar();
        QRect rect = ptr->geometry();
        rect.setTop(header()->height());
        ptr->setGeometry(rect);
    }

    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* ev) override
    {
        QTreeView::resizeEvent(ev);
        updateVertScrollBar();
    }
};
```

Depending on the `sizePolicy` the `updateVertScrollBar` method could be called just after data is filled or as presented in the sample implementation the update can occur for each `resizeEvent` - which should cover various resizing performed to the widget.

**EDIT**

Additionally removing the blank space left from the shrunk scrollbar would be tricky. First denote that the `QTreeView` is built from a viewport widget and scrollbars (among others). The issue you now see comes from the fact that viewport plus vertical scrollbar widths (if visible) should match and this is calculated internally.

I stated that it's tricky since there is a load of stuff happening when you try to force the size of these components. Some updates are called in-place some are called through the event loop. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271364/how-to-know-when-the-verticalscrollbar-is-showing/41282358#41282358) to get more detaile info about the concept. Similar approach is probably applied to `QTreeView`.

Basically what you would need to do is to stretch the viewport width. This should be probably done during the `resizeEvent` but calling from there methods like `viewport()->setGeometry()` might not end well - you might get caught into a loop. You might try `blockSignals` but I'm not sure this would help. In general if you want to mess with the internals of a given `Qt` widget you should go through it's implementation at least briefly.

Comment: this can be done, but there has a blank gap in the header which width equals the scrollbar's width, how can i remove the blank gap in the header??

Comment: Paste an image showing what you are experiencing. Just the region of interest around the scrollbar would be enough.

Comment: Added some additional info but not a direct solution which is not straightforward this time.

Comment: when the contents in treeview not more than one page, no scrollbar, no gap, but once the contents in treeview more than one page, the scroll bar and gap are displayed together